# Dynamic CSS property value that depends on its class/id name

Tags: css

I am wondering if there is a way to set a css property value dynamically that depends on its name. Like for example:

```
.m-b-5 {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Where 5px is referenced to its class/id name.

Comment: Not really. Using SASS or LESS this could be possible.

Comment: You can use Jquery for this if needed

Comment: Using of CSS 2 or CSS 3 It's not possible you need to use variables in SASS - Once check that resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pure CSS no. The only way with CSS is to create all the classes you'll use on the start:

```
.m-t-10{ margin-top: 10px }
.m-t-20{ margin-top: 20px }
.m-t-30{ margin-top: 30px }
/* etc margin */

.p-t-10{ padding-top: 10px }
.p-t-20{ padding-top: 20px }
.p-t-30{ padding-top: 30px }
/* etc padding */
```

Or you can use LESS/SCSS/some other CSS preprocessor to create a mixin/function which creates those classes.

[Boostrap V4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#spacing) included the same feature so [check the source code to get the idea](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/utilities/_spacing.scss).